# Integrate google workspaces and GCP Virtual desktops for user access to GCP DaaS

Tags: g-suite, vdi

I want to connect my google workspaces (G Suite) to my GCP virtual desktops (windows 10) for user authentication. I understand I can use my google workspaces domain controller (I use loosely) to manage access to virtual desktops (like AWS workspaces).
The use case. I create a user in google workspace and then select the user for the virtual desktop. Then a virtual desktop will spin up for the user to login to, using their google workspace credentials. I want to know how to do that.
I understand how to create virtual desktops on GCP. I do not know how to integrate them with google workspaces domain. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be interested in is the Google Credential Provider for Windows. This allows you to SSO into Windows with your Cloud Identity account your users are using for Google Workspace.

You can find more details about this feature here:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/9541083?hl=en

I have not tried this in a VDI setting myself, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Definitely interested to hear how it goes!